# LinearLayout vertical ajustar altura de elementos contenidos

Tags: android, xml

Tengo un `LinearLayout` con tres elementos, uno de los cuales es un `BottomNavigationView`, el cual quisiera que se muestre siempre en la parte inferior de la pantalla, en la parte superior un `AppBarLayout` y al medio un `RelativeLayout` que ocupe el resto de la pantalla, tengo el siguiente `xml`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor_principal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">

    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

He intentado con `layout_weight` para cada elemento dentro del `LinearLayut`, pero no sé si es la manera más apropiada.

Este es mi resultado con el anterior `xml`, no existe la distribución que necesito.

[image: linearLayout con tres elementos]

Answer (score 1):

Cuando defines un ancho o alto y al mismo tiempo estableces un valor para `layout_weight`, no surtirá efecto ya que lo que hace `layout_weight` es distribuir el espacio restante en el `ViewGroup` entre los elementos de manera proporcional si por ejemplo le das 1 al primer view y 2 a otro view significa que el espacio restante lo divides en 3 partes de las cuales 2 la tendrá el segundo view. Ok una vez se ha hecho esta distribución del espacio restante, la proporción de espacio restante que se le asigno a una view se adiciona al ancho o alto (dependiendo de la orientación) que la view tiene.

Para que funcione tu distribución de espacio debes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor_principal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">

    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Ahora si si sumas los enteros en la propiedad weight de cada view obtendrías 16, tu `BottomNavigationView` tendrá 10 partes de tu espacio disponible,el relative layout tendrá 5 y tu appBar tendrá 1. Dependiendo de la orientación de tu `LinearLayout` deberás establecer el `layout_width` o el `layout_height` de tu view a 0 para que la división del espacio restante sea tomando en cuenta todo el alto y ancho que hay en el viewgroup.

Answer (score 1):

BottomNavigationView tiene que tener como altura android:layout_height="wrap_content". Después el relative layout tiene que adaptarse al alto que falta del LinearLayout. Por ello se utiliza estos parámetros:

> android:layout_height="0dp"
>       android:layout_weight="1"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor_principal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Otra solución a este problema es utilizar un RelativeLayout en vez de el LinearLayout y poner el contenido debajo del AppBarLayout y por encima de BottomNavigationView.